# how to read the title's number in Word using POI

Tags: java, apache-poi, ms-office

In a `Word` document structured as follows:

```
1  Title 1
   1.1  title 1.1
   1.2  title 1.2
        1.2.1  title 1.2.1
   1.3  title 1.3
```

I can read the title using [poi](/questions/tagged/poi), but no way to read the number before title generated automatically.

I'd like to know if there is a way to read it using [poi](/questions/tagged/poi)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am afraid you will have to calculate it yourself, here are the methods you can use on the `XWPFParagraph` object to extract the data you need:

- [XWPFParagraph#getNumLevelText()](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFParagraph.html#getNumLevelText--) Returns the text of the numbering with placeholder
- [XWPFParagraph#getNumIlvl()](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFParagraph.html#getNumIlvl--) Returns the depth of the title
- [XWPFParagraph#getNumFmt()](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFParagraph.html#getNumFmt--) Returns the format or the title numbering (decimal, roman, lowerletter, ..)

You can use them this way:

```
for (XWPFParagraph paragraph : paragraphList) {
    System.out.println("text: "+paragraph.getNumLevelText());
    System.out.println("depth: "+paragraph.getNumIlvl());
    System.out.println("format: "+paragraph.getNumFmt());
}
```

I tried on this file:

[image]

and it outputs:

```
text: %1.
depth: 0
format: decimal

text: %1.%2.
depth: 1
format: decimal

text: %1.%2.
depth: 1
format: decimal

text: %1.%2.%3.
depth: 2
format: decimal

text: %1.%2.
depth: 1
format: decimal
```

So from there you will know for each title what is its format. You need to evaluate it yourself.

**EDIT**

This might work for your. As you have only decimals, it is a simple case.

```
int[] levelCurrentValues = new int[] {0,0,0};

for (XWPFParagraph paragraph : paragraphList) {
    String levelText = paragraph.getNumLevelText();
    BigInteger levelDepth = paragraph.getNumIlvl();
    String levelFormat = paragraph.getNumFmt();
    System.out.println("text: "+levelText);
    System.out.println("depth: "+levelDepth);
    System.out.println("format: "+levelFormat);

    if(levelText!=null) {
        levelCurrentValues[levelDepth.intValue()] += 1;

        levelText = levelText.replace("%1", "" + levelCurrentValues[0]);
        levelText = levelText.replace("%2", "" + levelCurrentValues[1]);
        levelText = levelText.replace("%3", "" + levelCurrentValues[2]);
        System.out.println(levelText);
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

When running against the same file as above, it outputs

```
text: %1.
depth: 0
format: decimal
1.

text: %1.%2.
depth: 1
format: decimal
1.1.

text: %1.%2.
depth: 1
format: decimal
1.2.

text: %1.%2.%3.
depth: 2
format: decimal
1.2.1.

text: %1.%2.
depth: 1
format: decimal
1.3.
```

Comment: this is including Table of content too